# Failed importing: Attribute "name" was already specified for element "option"

Tags: rundeck

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='PDATE' value='${DATE:yyyyMMdd}' />
        <option name='TSTAMP' value='${DATE:yyyy-MM-dd&apos;T&apos;HH.mm.ssXX}' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <description>Load Adjustment Transactions</description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>PointsUpdate</group>
    <id>6475eb91-926f-476b-bf05-85f5e8b22eae</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>sglp-jbadjust</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>true</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <schedule>
      <dayofmonth />
      <month day='*' month='*' />
      <time hour='00' minute='00' seconds='00' />
      <year year='*' />
    </schedule>
    <scheduleEnabled>false</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='sequential'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo one  ${option.PDATE} two ${option.TSTAMP} three</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

`git-import` importing this gives me errors, but I do not know why:

```
Failed importing: rundeck/jobs/PointsUpdate_0014.xml: rundeck.controllers.JobXMLException: Unable to parse xml: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 110; Attribute "name" was already specified for element "option".
```

Importing into the Rundeck GUI works fine, no errors reported, and options are correct.

[image: rundeck graphical user interface]

Answer (score 0):

I just imported your job and also tested using Tomcat 9 + Rundeck 2.4.3 + Linux. I'm not able to reproduce this error. May you provide additional data about Rundeck version,installation method,OS?

[Importing using GIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugcgT.png)

[Importing using GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzx4d.png)

Comment: It appears to be working after I deleted all jobs in the project and imported them again.